# State becomes undefined while calling 'UPDATE_DATA' action from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here is the code for react reducer. When I update data, the state becomes "undefined".

```js
const intialState = { data: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('formData')) || [] };

const formReducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_DATA':
      return { ...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload] };
    case 'UPDATE_DATA':
      {
        console.log('form update data dispatch', action.payload);
        const { id, data } = action.payload;
        const newData = state.data;
        newData.map((item, index) => {
          if (item[0].uid == id) {
            alert(item[0].uid === id);
            newData[index] = data;
            return (state.data = newData);
          }
        });
      }
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default formReducer;
```

I am using `useSelector()` to get updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UPDATE_DATA` case, you are not returning the updated state. This is causing the state to become `undefined`. The `return` statement inside the `map` callback returns the item in the array, and not the state.

You can rewrite that case like this:

```js
case 'UPDATE_DATA': {
  const { id, data } = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    data: state.data.map(item => {
      return item.uid === id ? data : item;
    }),
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues in the `UPDATE_DATA` reducer case:

1. The *next* state value isn't not returned from the case so upon this action being processed the state will be undefined.
2. `Array.prototype.map` returns an array and its callback should be a pure function, it shouldn't be used to mutate an external reference or the array it is iterating over.
3. `newData` is a reference to the current `state.data` so the reducer case is also mutating the current state instead of returning a ***new*** state/array reference.

A more correct implementation should look like the following:

```js
case 'UPDATE_DATA':
  const { id, data } = action.payload;
  const newData = state.data.map((item) => { // <-- return new array reference
    if (item[0].uid == id) {
      return data;
    }
    return item;
  });
  return newData; // <-- return next state value
```

or a bit more succinctly:

```js
case 'UPDATE_DATA':
  const { id, data } = action.payload;
  return state.data.map((item) => item[0].uid == id ? data : item);
```